# How to proxy ftp connection between IPV4 server to an IPV6 client and vice versa

Tags: ftp, nat, ipv6, ipv4

We have a gateway solution which connects legacy RADIO's having ftp server running with IPV4 interface to DU's running with IPV4 ftp clients to do file upload and download operations.
And currently we use ftp-proxy to proxy the ftp connection between different IPV4 ip addresses.

Now we need to support DU interface with IPV6 so we need to transmit ftp connections between IPV4 to IPV6.

What can be best replacement for ftp-proxy? And how to use those? I heard few things squid, socat, nat-pt, but I m very new to this. So any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Br,
Neeraj

Answer (score 0):

FTP is a weird old protocol. Software that can help it proxy between different address families will be hard to find.

Instead, consider implementing transition or tunneling methods to enable "IPv4 as a service".  [NAT64/DNS64](https://blogs.infoblox.com/ipv6-coe/even-more-methods-of-providing-ipv4-as-a-service-ipv4aas-part-3/) is one way. In short, synthesizing DNS records with embedded IPv4 addresses, and letting a dual stack NAT64 device translate.